# c++ initialisation order of static members

Tags: c++, initialization

Just wondering if in the following the static members are initialised before the Foo class object is initialised. Since both are static variables, one a static member and the other a static global variable, initialisation order is not guaranteed or specified.

```
struct Foo
{
   Foo() { assert(a == 7); }

   
   static inline int a = 7;
};

Foo foo;

int main()
{

}
```

So the initialisation order between the global Foo and the static class member is not defined, you would think there is no guarantee. However, I'm thinking that before a Foo is instantiated that the Foo class would need to be completed/initialised first, and so in that case that there might be a guarantee that the static member variable would be initialised first.

Comment: `a` being a member of a type of `foo` doesn't matter. But even without that, `a` seems to be initialized first because its initializer is constexpr, or, ignoring that, because it's higher in the source code (if I'm reading [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) correctly).

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking that before a Foo is instantiated that the Foo class would need to be completed/initialised first

That is not generally the case, so you should be careful with that assumption.

---

However, in your specific example, the order of initialization is guaranteed. The initializer of `a` is a constant expression and therefore `a` will be constant-initialized. Constant-initialization is guaranteed to happen before any dynamic initialization, which the initialization of `foo` is.

---

Even if `a` was not constant-initialized, there wouldn't be an issue here, because `foo` is defined after `a` in the same translation unit, `foo` is not an inline or template variable *and* because `Foo` is not a template. If either of these requirements were not fulfilled, there could be problems in the ordering guarantees.